# Options to fix a stripped driveside BB thread- Shimano BB-93

Tags: frames, repair, bottom-bracket

I removed the BB (Shimano BB-93) from my Canondale Trail and found the drive side thread is stripped on BB and frame.

See [image: the stripped frame thread] and [image: the stripped BB thread]

What are the options for me to replace the BB?

Is there an alternative part which will reach the good thread or other alternative?

I'm aware there could be a machining/welding/tapping option, but would guess that would not be worthwhile on an ageing bike.

Are there any alternative parts I could use?

[Sheldon Brown](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bottombrackets.html) mentions a Velo-orange option that clamps in place, but if possible I'd like to keep my recently replaced Hollowtech II crankset if possible

I'm baffled by all the combinations, hoping someone has been down this path already and can suggest if there's a practical solution.